# Given prior art, is Facebook's patent on Reactions valid?

Tags: prior-art-request, prior-art, facebook, us8918339, path

In reference to the patent: [US8918339](https://patents.google.com/patent/US8918339B2/en), it would seem to me that the Path (social network) had this same implementation years before Facebook.

Its been easy to find, via search engines, a number of screenshots from 2012 and earlier that appear to pre-date the patent.

See also:

1. "[With Reactions, Facebook Supercharges The Like Button With 6 Empathetic Emoji](https://techcrunch.com/2015/10/08/with-reactions-facebook-supercharges-the-like-button-with-6-empathetic-emoji/)". TechCrunch article notes Path image form 2012
2. "[Path Tries Again With a Wider Network](http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/11/29/path-2-0-hopes-to-differ-from-other-social-networks/)" - NYTimes, Nov 2011, with screenshot
3. "[Path for Apple iOS, Android: Mobile Social Network Review](http://anewdomain.net/2012/01/21/path-smartphones-apple-ios-and-android-social-network-review/)" - Jan 2012

Wouldn't that be grounds enough to make this patent invalid? Does anyone have more examples?

Answer (score 1):

Without a deeper dive, you might have a case against the broadest one of the independent claims: claim 10.
However, independent claims 1 and 15 also contain a pay-for-emoji feature:
"prompting the viewing user for payment information associated with the selected emoji;"

It is not clear at all if Path had this functionality.